# Copy data from one workbook to another based on column A values and specific column headers

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy and paste data from a workbook to the destination file based on two conditions:

1. Match the values located in column A in Row 8 - add a condition IF the value from column A in destfile is not found paste the "-" only in matchingheaders, the same thing if the value is "-"
2. Match the column headers - where in sourcefile there are only headers needed, but in the destfile there are more columns in different order.

The macro should allow duplicate values, so the data should be pasted twice.

In the code you may find typos. My working environment doesn't allow me to copy paste this.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Copy()

Dim srcWorkbook as workbook
Set srcWorkbook = Workbooks.Open ("M:\Desktop\Data.xlsm")
Dim srcSheet as Worksheet
Dim srcSheet=srcWrokbook.Worksheets("Data")

Dim srcRange as Range
Set srcRange=srcSheet.UsedRange

Dim headersSource as Variant
headersSource=srcSheet.Range("A1",srcSheetCells(1,srcRange.Columns.Count)).Value

DIm destWorkbook as Workbook
Set destWorkbook =ThisWorkbook
Dim destSheet as Worksheet
Set destSheet=destWorkbok.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim destRange as range
Dim destRange = destSheet.UsedRange

Dim destRow as Range
Dim destLastRow as Long
destLastRow = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim destValue as Variant

For Each destRow in destSheet.Range("A2:A" & destLastRow)
    destValue=destRow.value
    If Not IsEmpty(destValue) Then
        matchIndex = Application.Match(destValue, srcRange.Column(1),0)
        If Not IsError(matchIndex) Then
            Dim headerIndex as Long
            For headerIndex = 1 To UBound (headersSource,2)
                Dim headersDest as Variant
                headersDest = destSheet.Range("A1", destSheet.Cells(1, destRange.Columns.Count)).Value
                Dim matchHeaderIndex as Variant
                matchHeaderIndex = Application.match(headersDest, headersSource, 0)
                If not IsError (matchHeaderIndex) Then
                    destSheet.Cells(destRow.Row, headerIndex).Value = srcRange.Cells(matchIndex, matchHeaderIndex).Value ` This causing error 13.
                End If
            Next headerIndex
        End If
    End If
Next destRow

End Sub
```

Data in data feed
[image]

Where the data should be pasted
[image]

Comment: Can you add a sample input and expected output just with a few rows of data? an example easy to copy/paste and reproduce your code

Comment: Please see the screens above.

Comment: The common filed is ISSUERID in which the values from destSheet should be matched to value in sourceSheet. However the sourceSheet contains all available data, but I need only for these that are in destSheet. Notice that destSheet - ISSUERID can also have a values "-" and unfortunatelly i has to stay that way. The headers are also the common field in both sheets, but in destSheet there are more headers and they can`t be in the same order. To sum up what I need is to macro find the ISSUERID value in sourceSheet, and will paste the data in destSheet in respecitive column (based on header name)

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit from VLOOKUP combined with MATCH to bring your desired output. Your source data is perfect to use with VLOOKUP, you just need to change what column you want to bring and you can use MATCH for that:

My example works on same workbook but you just need to adapt it to work on ranges of different workbooks. The main process is done

```
Sub TETS()
Dim SourceData As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim LR As Long
Dim MatchColumn As Long
Dim MyF As WorksheetFunction
Set MyF = WorksheetFunction


Set SourceData = Range("A8").CurrentRegion 'all source data into range, including headers
'headers will be in row 1 of the range variable!

'in destiny, locate column ISSUERID and get last non blank row of that column
'we know ISSUERID is in row 8 but don't now which column, so use MATCH
MatchColumn = MyF.Match("ISSUERID", Range("8:8"), 0)
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, MatchColumn).End(xlUp).Row 'gotcha, last non blank cell in column ISSUERID in destiny

'now just loop trough headers in destiny and benefit from VLOOKUP to get desired output only if headers match
i = 9 'first headers column, IN MY EXAMPLE IS 9 BUT in yours will be 1 for sure (1 is column A)

Do Until Cells(8, i) = ""

    'check if current header exists in source data and is not ISSUERID
    If MyF.CountIf(SourceData.Rows(1), Cells(8, i)) > 0 And Cells(8, i) <> "ISSUERID" Then
        'there is match. Bring data with VLOOKUP combined with MATCH
        'extra condition: if ISSUERID not found then return "-"
        Range(Cells(9, i), Cells(LR, i)).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(COUNTIF(" & SourceData.Columns(1).Address(True, True, xlR1C1) & ",RC" & MatchColumn & ")=0,""-"",VLOOKUP(RC" & MatchColumn & "," & SourceData.Address(True, True, xlR1C1) & ",MATCH(R8C," & SourceData.Rows(1).Address(True, True, xlR1C1) & ",0),FALSE))"
        
        'now convert to values to get rid of formulas
        Range(Cells(9, i), Cells(LR, i)) = Range(Cells(9, i), Cells(LR, i)).Value
    Else
        'the header does not match, do nothing, leave column in blank or do whatever you want
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

Set MyF = Nothing
Set SourceData = Nothing

End Sub
```

This is how it works:

[image]

After executing code:

[image]

Notice in destiny field `Column 4` is blank because that header **is not** on source data.

The main idea of the code is to use this formula, that will bring the values in matching headers:

`=IF(COUNTIF($A$8:$A$16;$L9)=0;"-";VLOOKUP($L9;$A$8:$F$16;MATCH(I$8;$A$8:$F$8;0);FALSE))`

The formula above is coded exactly as this part:

```
"=IF(COUNTIF(" & SourceData.Columns(1).Address(True, True, xlR1C1) & ",RC" & MatchColumn & ")=0,""-"",VLOOKUP(RC" & MatchColumn & "," & SourceData.Address(True, True, xlR1C1) & ",MATCH(R8C," & SourceData.Rows(1).Address(True, True, xlR1C1) & ",0),FALSE))"
```

Also, please, notice this relevant part!

```
i = 9 'first headers column, IN MY EXAMPLE IS 9 BUT in yours will be 1 for sure (1 is column A)
```

Comment: The macro works in one sheet, but I`m unable to implement different worksheet into the code to make it work. I can see that the macro implement the formula:
IF(COUNTIF($A$8:$A$16;$L9)=0;"";VLOOKUP($L9;$A$8:$F$16;MATCH(I$8;$A$8:$F$8;0);FALSE))
But  there is no reference to sourceSheet to make it work. Can you help ?